# tera wallet not showing at checkout/order-pay/ wordpress

Tags: wordpress, rest

when we try to make payment using checkout url "checkout/order-pay/?{order-id}=true&key={key}" which is obtain by custom api, tera wallet option not displaying

when we try same with web it shows tera wallet option but not with checkout url obtain by custom api

Comment: Hi Jitendrasinh, can you add the version of WordPress, Terawallet, and other plugins that you're using.

Comment: @zzarbi Tera wallet Version is 1.3.15, Wordpress version is 5.4.1